# Is ngen used to compile .NET code into an binary that will not require .NET framework to be installed when running the code?

Tags: .net, ngen

I read the following paragraph on Wikipedia article about the CLR:

> Alternatively, the CIL code can be
>   compiled to native code in a separate
>   step prior to runtime by using the
>   Native Image Generator (NGEN). This
>   speeds up all later runs of the
>   software as the CIL-to-native
>   compilation is no longer necessary.

Does this mean that I can take any .NET program and compile it to a binary that will then be able to run on machine that doesnt have the .NET framework installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

It means that you won't need to run the JIT (Just-In-Time) compiler when you run the code, since it is already converted to machine code by NGen. The resulting binaries still have dependencies on the .Net framework, and this must be installed separately on the machine.

There are tools which package the .Net framework assemblies and include them in your binaries in a way which the .Net framework is not needed. Check out http://www.xenocode.com/. VMWare bought a tool called Thinstall, which I think can also do this: http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80).aspx) for Ngen where it states:

> Ngen.exe creates native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly.

means (to me) that Ngen just does what the JIT compiler does and saves the results. It doesn't say anything about including the .NET runtimes in the binaries.

Comment: It seems that this is pretty much EXACTLY what it does.  Also, note that it's not safe to distribute ngen'd binaries; the cross-module-inlining that the JITs do make ngen'd images require essentially identical libraries at runtime as at ngen time, so they could need to be rebuilt at the drop of a hat.  (I get the impression that not *every* library patch invalidates everything downstream, but that any library patch *could* need to do so.  And I'm not certain that this trick even applies to changes outside mscorlib.)

Answer (score 2):

´NGen´ just compiles your code. It doesn't statically link the entire .NET framework into it.

Mono, however, *does* have a static compiler and linker that can do this. That's for example how Mono's iPhone support works.